# Houghpeaks function in Hough transform ( matlab code )

Tags: hough-transform

Look at the houghpeaks function for Hough transform in matlab toolbox:

peaks = houghpeaks(H, numpeaks)

peaks = houghpeaks(..., param1, val1,param2, val2)

paramter:

'NHoodSize' : Two-element vector of positive **odd** integers: [M N].

Question: NHoodSize must be **odd**? why?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that be because otherwise you're not landing on a cell boundary?

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

vs.

```
1 2
3 4
```

In NHOOD calculations an element in the middle is being evaluated and somehow being influenced by the surrounding values.